# Printing substrings in each line of string Python 3.5

Tags: python, ftp

I would have a huge list of Nasdaq stocks defined as a variable. 
Here's the code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

def my_function(data):
    print(data.decode())

ftp = FTP('ftp.nasdaqtrader.com')
ftp.login()
nasdaq=ftp.retrbinary('RETR /SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt', my_function)
```

If I print out the string "nasdaq" I can see it comes in the following format:

```
AAAP|Advanced Accelerator Applications S.A. - American Depositary Shares|Q|N|N|100|N|N
AAL|American Airlines Group, Inc. - Common Stock|Q|N|N|100|N|N
AAME|Atlantic American Corporation - Common Stock|G|N|N|100|N|N
AAOI|Applied Optoelectronics, Inc. - Common Stock|G|N|N|100|N|N
and so on...
```

I want a list where only the tickers are printed out:

```
AAAP
AAL
AAME
AAOI
```

What is the right approach to do this?

Comment: What is your current approach to do it? Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: You could use the string `split()` method at pipes ("|"), which will return a list. The first item in the list should be the ticker

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Why would my post be a duplicate? The post you mention does extract a substring from a bigger string but doesn't relate to having to loop on more lines.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that you can split on a delimiter of a newline character?

Comment: Yes, I can get the substring in between '\r\n' (new line) and "|" (goes after every ticker). What makes me struggle is the repeating process, I'm not sure how to loop this to get the substring of each line. And I think your post doesn't mention that @TigerhawkT3

Comment: By "What makes me struggle is the repeating process" do you mean that you're unfamiliar with loops entirely?

Comment: Not entirely, I'm just a begginer who still struggles on how to apply theory in real problems. I hope there is something I can do to enhance my question because I really don't know where to get more useful insight. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: It sounds like you need to brush up with a tutorial. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for answering :) @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 0):

```
print '\n'.join(share.split('|')[0] for share in nasdaq.splitlines())
```

Comment: OP said it's a "huge" list, so processing the whole thing at once probably isn't a great plan.

Comment: "huge" is 3291 lines, that should not be too worrisome. But  I agree if the file might be bigger.

Comment: Please edit your answer, or you could be down-voted. As it is now, it's just a suggestion with no context. Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).